# Exception: [1007:CM_NOT_SUPPORTED] not support Row Expiration in GridDB

Tags: griddb

An error occurred when I’m trying to create a time series expiration. Following is the code I’m using

```
ContainerInfo containerInfo = new ContainerInfo();
List<ColumnInfo> columnList = new ArrayList<ColumnInfo>();
columnList.add(new ColumnInfo("timestamp", GSType.TIMESTAMP));
columnList.add(new ColumnInfo("value", GSType.FLOAT));
containerInfo.setColumnInfoList(columnList);
containerInfo.setRowKeyAssigned(true);

TimeSeriesProperties tsProp = new TimeSeriesProperties();
tsProp.setRowExpiration(1, TimeUnit.MINUTE);
tsProp.setExpirationDivisionCount(5);
containerInfo.setTimeSeriesProperties(tsProp);

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("host", "192.168.1.134");
props.setProperty("port", "10001");
props.setProperty("clusterName", "myCluster");
props.setProperty("user", "admin");
props.setProperty("password", "admin");
props.setProperty("database","public");
props.setProperty("transactionTimeout","5000");
props.setProperty("failoverTimeout","5000");
GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);
TimeSeries<Row> lctime1 = store.putTimeSeries("lctime", containerInfo, false);
System.out.println("create");
store.close();
```

> Exception in thread "main" com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.common.GSStatementException: [1007:CM_NOT_SUPPORTED] not support Row Expiration (address=192.168.1.134:10001, partitionId=10)

Location where the error occurred

```
TimeSeries<Row> lctime1 = store.putTimeSeries("lctime", containerInfo, false);
```

How to solve this issue?